# What does "Sold On" mean?

Tags: meaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Sold” in the meaning of “bought”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27918/sold-in-the-meaning-of-bought)

I've read a tweet about iPhone 4S and this is what I saw:

> Totally **sold on** the iPhone 4S - for the dual core CPU and dual antenna
>   alone. I like fast things.

Can you guys give me an explanation about "sold on" and maybe some more usage.

Comment: @aedia: Yeah but unless people might google is "What does Sold On mean"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be *sold on something* means that you have been convinced of the merits of something (frequently that you've decided it's worth its cost, or is otherwise a worthwhile endeavor).

Some examples:

> After losing five pounds this week, I'm sold on this new diet.
>
> After seeing him play Hamlet, I'm sold on Bob as a dramatic actor.
>
> Tim sold me on the Mac as a desktop PC.
>
> I've been sold on running since I did my first 5k.

Comment: +1. deleting my answer, you got there first. :)